# C++ commands executing out of order

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I am attempting to make a simple shell program, and looking at a few examples have seen that most people use getline() to get input, however I have been trying to use read() and noticed a weird bug that I was wondering if other people saw or knew the cause of.

When I run the code using getline, everything works fine. After running the program I get the terminal name to show up and it is ready to accept input. When I use read it seems to be executing the name of the shell after taking in input. This seems to occur no matter what I do. the line to display the shell name is

```
cout << "SweetShell-> ";
```

and then AFTER this line I either run the read command, or even call another process which then runs the read command, and either way printing "SweetShell-> " happens AFTER the input.

Even weirder during testing I had a block of code like:

```
cout << "SweetShell-> ";
int test = read(0,buf,MAX_ARGS);
//temp is a string that is set to the input
cout << temp << "    " << test;
```

and the output looked something like this:

```
    3SweetShell-> ls
```

meaning it printed the spaces, then test, then the first cout, and finally temp. Anyone have any idea what is going on with this?

Comment: Oh by the way, along with my answer: C++ guarantees that these commands will be executed in order (so your title should be revised); it just doesn't guarantee that the output will be what you expect.

Comment: which OS is this running on? by your question it could be assumed to be Mac, Windows, Linux, etc.

Comment: Actually, I think to understand the behavior better, you should tell us exactly what `temp` is and what, if anything, that comment is replacing.

Comment: The OS is Linux, as for what exactly temp is it is a string. What is commented out there is a 7-8 line block that chops up the string into tokens, checks to see if certain tokens are equal to particular characters and then creates a vector that holds the chopped up string. I assumed it was irrelevant since none of the actions actually modified temp or dealt with input/output so I did not include them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try "flushing" the output buffer to make sure it prints in order. Try:

```
cout << "SweetShell-> " << std::flush;
int test = read(0,buf,MAX_ARGS);
//temp is a string that is set to the input
cout << temp << "    " << test << std::flush;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, this seemed to have completely fixed it I am somewhat new to C++ so I was unaware that you needed to flush it out like that.

Comment: @Someone: it just depends on the situation. Usually it's unnecessary, but `flush` *guarantees* that what you send to a stream (whether it's in your terminal display via `cout` or to a file) will be printed/written. If some intermediate function messes with the target of your buffers (i.e. printing to the terminal as well) before you flush them, as seems to be the case with `read`, you can have problems.

Comment: @Seth: "it just depends" is not accurate (details in my answer).

Comment: @Tony: I didn't mean that "magic" defines the situation. I just can't enumerate all the circumstances in a single comment post. For example, your answer missed the outrageous call of `system("echo hello there");`

Comment: @Seth: what's `system("echo hello there");` got to do with anything?  It won't flush `std::cout`....

Comment: @Tony: I didn't say it would. I was talking about "needing" to flush it out so that your output shows up in the same order as your statements in C++, which is the subject of the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Because the output is buffered, you need to [`flush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/flush/) the output before trying to `read()` your input.

Incidentally, be careful when combining raw OS-level `read(2)` and `write(2)` operations with buffered IO operations; while you can certainly use them both in the same program, using them both on the same *file* or *socket* is going to create trouble; so sticking with one form or the other will reduce the likelihood of introducing flaws in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the tips for the future, will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The crucial thing is that `std::cout` and `std::cin` are *tied* (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/tie/) - this means that streaming operations on `std::cin` will first trigger a flush on `std::cout`.  But, you're using the libC `read(...)` function which bypasses the C++ streams library altogether, therefore there's no chance for the flush to be invoked.  You could use `std::cin.read()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `cin >> test`? I always use `<iostream>` functions for console I/O; they work very well.

Comment: Although in general I prefer iostreams, they are really ***really*** slow compared to C I/O functions. So, when there's a lot of IO going on, I switch to printf, scanf etc.